# How to know the View Elements after loading a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, layout-inflater

I am trying to write code , where after loading the Layout , i want to know which are the view elements are related to the layout like TextView, EditText , Checkbox etc.

**MyCode :**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.demo_layout, null);
    // How to get to know about the UI Elements related to this layout //

    }


}
```

**demo_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout 
           android:id="@+id/lnr"    
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#ddccee"
           android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Test Layout"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edit1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Test Layout"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"/>


        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Test Layout"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

This layout has TextView , EditText , so , i want to know how to get UI elements are related to this layout programmatically.

So , please suggest me some solution.

Comment: You need to initialize your all UIs giving a reference of your inflated view object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getChildCount` [REF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount()) to get the count of views added to`ViewGroup` and then use `getChildAt` [REF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)) to get the `View` at given index.

You are using `LinearLayout` as base layout which already extends the `ViewGroup` Just change below line.

```
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.demo_layout, null);
```

Comment: Yes thanks but how can use ViewGroup... in the Activity

Comment: yes this we can do that , so we need to have CustomView class

Comment: yes i did view.getChildCount() , so i am getting value as 1 , but i think it should come 3 right... , please let me what's the problem

Comment: Your primary LinearLayout has one child layout so value is 1 now if you get the child count at this layout that will e three

Comment: great i understood , but if i want consider the inner LinearLayout then , how can i get the child count...

Comment: If you already know the View ids you should use view.findViewById() by passing the view id this is better approach. Above approach is when view ids are not known.

Comment: yes findViewById is good approach , i am only trying to it , when there will be many ui elements will be there in a layout. May be we can consider a big online registration form

Comment: In that case keep getting the views by index and then check if its ViewGroup instance then get the child count for that and get views for that view group. This way you can get all views

Comment: So there will be an array of views

Comment: No Array you keep using the approach as in answer just keep checking if view you got is viewgroup then get its child also

Comment: can we get to know the ViewGroup after loading a layout

Comment: After getting the View you can always check instanceof ViewGroup for that View

Comment: so like this  if(view instanceof LinearLayout){
    
   }

Comment: In Place of LinearLayout set ViewGroup

Comment: but the child count will always come 1 for the post layout , so can i get 3 childcount

Comment: hey i found it check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597230/loop-through-all-subviews-of-an-android-view/18980154#18980154

Answer (score 0):

After you've inflated your `demo_layout` just call `findViewById` on your `view` instance like this:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.demo_layout, null);
TextView txt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
```

Comment: oh !! man , this thing every Android developers knows , i want to know , how to get to know there is a Textview in the layout programatically

Comment: yes no issue , may be you just misunderstood the question , but no worries , so can you please suggest me some solution

Answer (score 0):

Elements of `view` must be retrieved by `view.findViewById()`.
Except in activity you use findViewById() directly to retrieve view elements of the contentView you set in `setContentView()`.